# PHP passing array in session variable

Tags: php, session, variables

I am trying to get an array to pass in a session variable from one page to another.  I am setting the session variable equal to my the $_POST data collected from my form.  Printing the variable for test shows me that it is getting set initially on Page 1.

Page 1

```
session_start(); // start up your PHP session! 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


unset($_POST['submit']);
$_SESSION['userdata'] = $_POST;
$userqty=$_POST;
print_r($_SESSION['userdata']);
```

On Page 2 I am trying to set it equal to another variable.  Again I test to see if the array has passed to page 2 but it doesn't and I get an error for not having a valid array for the **array_sum** function

session_start(); // start up your PHP session!

```
$_SESSION['userdata'] = $userqty;

print_r($_SESSION['userdata']);

print_r($userqty;);

$userqty_total=array_sum($userqty);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're essentially setting `$_SESSION['userdata']` to `null` on page 2. Switch the assignment order: `$userqty = $_SESSIOn['userdata'];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting `$_SESSION['userdata']` to the value of `$userqty`, which is uninitialized.

Change your first line to:

```
session_start();
$userqty = $_SESSION['userdata']
```

Answer (score 2):

checkout [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and unserialize functions in php.

EDIT: actually you need not convert the array to string and convert it back to array. You can use it as it is.

on first page:

```
$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST;
```

on second page:

```
$temp = $_SESSION['data'];
```

now `$temp` has the `$_POST` contents of page 1.

Answer (score 0):

in page1:

```
 session_start();
 $array  = array("appel","car","human");
 $_SESSION['array'] = $array ;
```

in page2:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($nom); $i++) {
        echo $array[$i] . ' ';
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO,
To make it easier to understand your answer, please explain briefly what you did here.